# mysqli_fetch_assoc only returning one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have used this code many times in the past, and it has returned many rows of data before...now it is only returning one.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['action'];    
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're initialising a single set of variables. Each time the loop runs, the previous values are being over-written.

Comment: Put `echo` in a `while`-loop.

Comment: I've tried it in both places (inside the while loop and outside), same result. And yes, it seems they are being overwritten, but I've litteraly tried echoing echo purely just echo $row["action"]; and it still only returned one result...how can that be possible to overwrite that?

Comment: It's not `$echo $action`, but `echo $action`, you're doing so, right ?

Comment: Maybe there's only one row in your table? What shows `mysqli_stmt_num_rows`?

Comment: no, there's 3 as of now (via phpmyadmin)

Comment: I edited my code, to show you just how simple i get my code down to and it still only echos 1 row..

Comment: Are you 10000% sure you're talking to the same database as you're looking at in phpmyadmin? Have you tried inserting a new record via PHP?

Comment: Try this 
$i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $responce["result"][$i]=$row;
      $i=$i+1;
  }
echo json_encode($responce);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    print_r($row);   
}
```

It will show **all your `$row` content**, I'm pretty sure it will help.

You can see more about the `print_r()` function **[in the php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)**

Comment: I added the echo $row['action']; inside this, and it works. I think i figured out why your code worked and mine didn't. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you do it this way?

```
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$rows  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

foreach ($row in $rows) {
    echo $row['action'];
}
```

Also, you could enhance your query's performance by doing `SELECT action FROM jobs` (as it's the only field you're using).

Comment: try this
$i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $responce["result"][$i]=$row;
      $i=$i+1;
  }